# EC2 Tomcat can’t connect to MySQL

Tags: jdbc, amazon-ec2, tomcat8, mysql-connector

I’m working on an Amazon EC2 instance of Amazon Linux, having followed [this tutorial](http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/11/set-up-an-amazon-ec2-instance-with-tomcat-and-mysql-5-minutes-tutorial/) precisely, but I can’t work out how to connect Tomcat to MySQL. How am I meant do do this?

### What I’ve tried

I have traversed the directories within `/usr/share/tomcat8` and, for each directory:

1. placed the Connector/J file, `mysql-connector-java-5.1.45-bin.jar`, obtained from [here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.1.html), in the directory
2. restarted Tomcat
3. reloaded my index page, `app/index.jsp`
4. got an error: `javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Unable to get connection, DataSource invalid: "java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc/foo"` from line 8 of `/index.jsp`

I have placed a copy of the Connector/J jar file among my other Java libraries and added it to my classpath, despite the obvious futility of this approach given how Tomcat handles its classpath.

I have reduced my code about as much as I reasonably can in the hope that something else I’d done had produced this phenomenon as a side effect. Since less than fifty lines of code continue to produce the same error, that’s probably not the case, but technically I haven’t ruled it out.

### My files

`/usr/share/tomcat8/webapps/app/index.jsp`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ page import="java.io.*, java.util.*, java.sql.*, javax.servlet.http.*, javax.servlet.*" @>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="sql" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" %>
<% Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").getInstance(); /* for good measure */ %>
<html>
    <body>
        <sql:query dataSource="jdbc/foo" var="result">
            SELECT name FROM Users;
        </sql:query>
        <c:forEach var="r" items="${result.rows}">
            <c:out value="${r.name}"/><br/>
        </c:forEach>
    </body>
</html>
```

`/usr/share/tomcat8/webapps/app/META-INF/context.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Context>
    <Resource name="jdbc/foo" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource" maxTotal="64"
              maxIdle="16" maxWaitMillis="10000" username="user" password="password"
              driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/foo"/>
</Context>
```

`/usr/share/tomcat8/webapps/app/WEB-INF/web.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                             http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         version="4.0"
         metadata-complete="true>

    <request-character-encoding>UTF-8></request-character-encoding>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <resource-ref>
        <description>Database connection</description>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/foo</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>
</web-app>
```

My database has a user `'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password'` with `SELECT` privileges on `foo.*`. Database `foo` has a table `Users(email varchar(127) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, name varchar(127) NOT NULL);`

### Conclusion

It’s probable that I’ve missed something silly, since this is my first time doing anything on Tomcat outside of my local machine (on which this works just fine, by the way). Can anybody find what I’m doing wrong? (Aside from my debugging process itself: I’m fully aware of how horrible that is.)

TL/DR: I’ve tried a bunch of things and Tomcat still can’t connect to MySQL on my EC2 instance.

### Edit

To be clear, since I’m being instructed to place `mysql-connector-java-5.1.45-bin.jar` in various places or asked where I put it: I’ve tried putting it in *literally every directory* within `tomcat8`.

Comment: Exactly where did you put the Connector/J jar? The folder `/usr/share/tomcat8` would be the wrong place. It should probably be `/usr/share/tomcat8/lib`, although I'm not 100% sure about the directory layout, it may need to go in a `lib` directory elsewhere in the Tomcat setup.

Comment: I state in my question that I have tried placing the jar in all of the subdirectories of `/usr/share/tomcat8/`; this includes `/usr/share/tomcat8/lib/` and the only other potentially relevant `lib` I can think of, `/usr/share/tomcat8/webapps/foo/WEB-INF/lib/`.

Comment: Is your jar really called `mysql-connector-java-5.1.4.4-bin.jar`, specifically the 5.1.4.4 part (and not 5.1.44)? As that would be an ancient version of the driver that doesn't contain the driver autoloading information given version 5.1.4 pre-dates Java 6.

Comment: I swapped it out for a new one.  Same problem.

Comment: Actually, no, the error changed: it’s no longer telling me which file and line number produced the error.

Comment: Have had the same issue, any resolution?

Comment: I’ve got nothing except “give up on EC2,” which I understand might not be an option for everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not technically doing anything wrong, I have experienced (Same setup as above tomcat and mysql) and rectified this issue on my side, you can validate by having a JSP Database test page not using DataSource, the issue is that most **Amazon services** do not support things out of the box:

- JNDI Datasource

EC2 including Beanstalk lack this feature, as per your code above:

- dataSource="jdbc/foo"

Solution is to either resort to:

1. JDBC DriverManager
2. Create JNDI Datasource

References:

- https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=108499
- https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=313642
- https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

Option 1 : Place the file "mysql-connector-java-5.1.4.4-bin.jar" inside your tomcat lib folder

Option 2 : Place the file "mysql-connector-java-5.1.4.4-bin.jar" inside the lib folder of your application "foo"

Option 3 : Place the file "mysql-connector-java-5.1.4.4-bin.jar" inside the java classpath.

Comment: As outlined in the body of my question, I have tried putting `mysql-connector-java-5.1.4.4-bin.jar` in each directory within `tomcat8`, which I’m fairly certain includes the suggested locations (assuming you mean `tomcat8/lib/` and `tomcat8/webapps/foo/WEB-INF/lib/`).

Comment: I have added option 3 to my answer. Please try pacing the mysql connector file inside the java classpath

Comment: I also mentioned that I tried that, although Tomcat ignores it.